# How to properly display the counter result between the increment and decrement button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, bootstrap-4

I am learning angular and I created a component `quantity-component`. In quantity-component.component.html, there will be 2 buttons for increment denoted by `+` and decrement `-` and decrement is enabled only when the counter value > 0.

When I click on `+`, the counter starts increasing and the decreases when I click `-`.

I am getting the counter properly increased and decreased but didn't get the design properly.

I need it like : [image: Output I needed]

But I am getting like this :

[image: Current Output]

Following are my .html and .ts code

HTML code

```html
<div>
  <h2>Quantity Selector</h2>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "onDecrement()" [disabled]="counter <= 0"
      data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
      </button>
      <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number" value="{{this.counter}}" >
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  (click)= "onIncrement()" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
  </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

TS code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quantity-component',
  templateUrl: './quantity-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quantity-component.component.css']
})
export class QuantityComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  counter: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onDecrement() {
    this.counter -= 1;
    return this.counter;
  }

  onIncrement() {
    this.counter += 1;
    return this.counter;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add class `text-center` in your input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number text-center" value="{{this.counter}}" >
```

Comment: This only moves the text to the center which is not I am looking for. I need the area in between the + and - button like I mentioned in the question